# Sprite Image Is Not Being Generated

Tags: disassembly

When I try to generate a sprite image, I get the following error in my scout window:

> 0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in run! C:\Program Files (x86)\Scout\bin\compass:12:in `(root)'

How can I resolve this issue, Someone please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: //@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
//@import "icons/*.png"; this is my code for Sprite generation

Comment: My code is <code>@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icons/*.png"; </code>

Comment: Please edit this into your question.